# save value of selected item in listbox with VBA

Tags: vba, listbox

I've a problem who drive me crazy.
I'm working in a VBA script with Access, and i need to save in a variable the value of list box.
At the moment was able just save the the item list order (starting from 0), but i want to save the highlighted line value instead.
how I can reach this?
Thank you so much,
Regards,
Riccardo

Comment: If it's a single selection listbox, use its value property `ListBoxName.Value`.

Comment: Hello Kostas, unfortunately it isn't, is a multi-selection listbox... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to loop to get the selected items.

```
Dim item As Variant

For Each item In YourListBox.ItemsSelected
    MsgBox YourListBox.ItemData(item)
Next
```

---

To store the selected items in an array:

```
Dim arr() As Variant, item As Variant

With YourListBox

    ReDim arr(.ItemsSelected.Count - 1)
    
    For Each item In .ItemsSelected
        arr(item - 1) = .ItemData(item)
    Next
    
End With
```

---

You can also flatten the array with the `Join` function.

```
Dim s As String
s = Join(arr, ",") 

Debug.Print s
```

Comment: Thank you so much Kostas, it works exactly as i expected, thank you so much!!!